# Omit nth first lines in awk but keep them in output

Tags: bash, awk, tabular

I've a tabular file composed of the tabular data and a header that I must keep along during my workflow -and that complicates everything-. I was wondering if there's some way to omit the nth first lines in the file, use `awk` (eg, for column filtering) and adding them again in the final output.

A possible solution (but a bit complex, I think) is to create a temporary file with the header, do `awk 'NR>10 {command}'` and after add the the header again... something like this:

```
head -10 file > header_tmp.txt
awk 'NR>10 {$5 ~ /\//; print}' file | cat header_tmp.txt - > final_file
```

Maybe there's another more tricky solution ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself. Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With awk, you can use NR keyword and do something like this :

```
awk 'NR<50{print}NR>=50{<code for lines >=50>}'
```

or

```
awk 'NR<50{print;next;}{<codes for lines >=50>}'
```

Example : I want to keep the 3 first lines, sum values for the others.

Input :

```
Hello World1
Hello World2
Hello World3
1;2;3;4
5;6;7;8
```

Code :

```
awk -F';' 'NR<4{print;next}{result=0;for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){result += $i}; print result}' test.txt
```

Result :

```
Hello World1
Hello World2
Hello World3
10
26
```

---

Easier with the example you provided :

```
awk -F\; 'NR<=10;(NR>10)&&($5 ~ /\//)' file
```

will print first ten lines and all the other lines where $5 satisfies `/\//`

Comment: That's nice! Thanks a lot!